# Optimising Splitting of Files

Tags: c#

Hi i currently use the following code to split a file into muliple 2mb smaller parts.

```
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 20 * 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(inputFile)) {
    int index = 0;
    while (input.Position < input.Length) {
        using (Stream output = File.Create(path)) {
            int remaining = chunkSize, bytesRead;
            while (remaining > 0 && (bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0,
                        Math.Min(remaining, BUFFER_SIZE))) > 0) {
                output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                remaining -= bytesRead;
            }
        }
    }
    index++;
}
```

This works perfectly, and will split a 10mb file into 5 x 2mb files 0.part,2.part ect...

I would like to know how I would generate just part 3 again knowing the chunkSize always stays at 2mb. I can achieve this by wrapping in an if,else and evaluating index, but with a 1GB file this process can take a while to loop through.  I'd like to understand this function more and how I can just get the part of the file I require?

Comment: You could use [Stream.Seek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx) to seek to the correct location (i.e. Seek to the position `3*2mb`): `input.Seek(3 * 2 * 1024 * 1024 , SeekOrigin.Begin);`. Make sure you check the return value to ensure you've seeked to the correct place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`input.Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.position(v=vs.110).aspx) property is settable. If you know that you need part 3, set `Position` to `2*chunkSize` to skip the first two chunks, and do the innermost `while` loop once to copy from that position to the output:

```
int desiredChunkNumber = 3;
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(inputFile)) {
    input.Position = (desiredChunkNumber - 1) * chunkSize;
    using (Stream output = File.Create(path)) {
        int remaining = chunkSize, bytesRead;
        while (remaining > 0 && (bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0,
                    Math.Min(remaining, BUFFER_SIZE))) > 0) {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            remaining -= bytesRead;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, I did not realise input.Position was settable! :)